# A simple word or phrase that describes a non-conflict "day in the life" story introduction

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I tell my students that I want their stories to start out as normal "day in the life" explorations of the world they're writing about. I'd like to find a better way of saying that. I'm not looking for a technical writing term necessarily but a simple easy to understand description of a type of story introduction or even a state of being where nothing outrageous is happening, no conflict or big changes.

I've used the words innocuous, boring, and mundane in the past, but those have a negative feel to them and I have to re-explain that I still want the story introductions to be engaging, but no big changes right off the bat.

Appreciate any suggestions of words or short simple phrases that might help me out. Thanks.

Comment: The term is `Slice Of Life` comes to mind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_of_life . However, it might not be an  accessible term for all students.

Comment: So you want them to write a **feel-good** story and it shouldn't have a **cold opening.**

Comment: The challenge seems to be that "story" often indicates plot (a beginning, middle and end drawn around a tension/plot arc's establishment rise and resolution). What you are describing is a simple narrative.

Comment: Thanks @R.S., slice of life is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Happy to help.  Hope the students' stories make for interesting  read. The term is widely used in advertising as well ,and slice of life ads are very easy to identify. Maybe your can point that to your students.

Comment: "ordinary, typical or average day". For example, the English title of the French play "une journée ordinaire" with Alain Delon is "a typical day".

Comment: If "A day in the life" was good enough for [Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Day_in_the_Life_of_Ivan_Denisovich), what's the problem?

Comment: I know you don't want a "technical" term, but there's a word for this often used by creative writers in discussing plot:  **stasis** (establishing the normal routine for characters).  I'm still looking for a good academic online source for this.

Answer (score 0):

I posit Naturalistic

> 1. derived from or closely imitating real life or nature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalism_(literature)